# shibd daemon 'timeout' on systemctl start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl, shibboleth

I have a server that uses the shibboleth2 shibd daemon to allow remote authentication to a database.

The daemon reads a very large federation metadata file on starting/reloading (circa 34MB). This needs several minutes to process.

Previously it completed within the systemctl timeout limit of 90 seconds. It is noe exceeding this limit.

I have attempted to extend the systemctl timeout without success by editing /etc/systemd/system.conf in the following way:

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=600s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=300s
```

This should override the default timeout of 90 seconds.

I then ran

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl daemon-reexec
```

to attempt to reload systemctl configuration itself to enable the new timeout.

However the timeout appears to have remained the same, and the command

```
systemctl start shibd
```

Times out after about 5 minutes

Are there any suggestions as to what is going on here? I have not retried simply rebooting the server yet as it is a production server and would affect multiple applications.

Comment: Are the values reported by `systemctl show shibd.service -p TimeoutStartSec` `systemctl show shibd.service -p TimeoutStopSec`
`systemctl show shibd.service -p TimeoutSec` correct?

Comment: Hi @MarkWagner. Running those commands returned nothing at all, so I output all variable, and I got the following:` TimeoutStartUSec=5min`
`TimeoutStopUSec=5min`
`Result=timeout`
`JobTimeoutUSec=infinity`
`JobTimeoutAction=none`

Comment: FYI - the current timeout appears to be 5 minutes, not 1.5 minutes as I said. However it is still too short for the metadata to be validated and import.

Answer (score 1):

And excellent post explaining the process to extend the timeout is provided here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value/276785#276785